# regex : Extract from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been struggling with a regexp problem. 
I'm building a translator somehow and I'm trying to extract a string surrounded by two delimiter.

The start delimiter would be this : `CONDITIONS DEXTRACTION :`
The end delimiter would either be : `LISTER or CHARGER`

```
$subject = "CONDITIONS D’EXTRACTION : FAMCNT=&TYCNT
AND CGAR=&CODGAR
CHARGER LES PSEUDO VARIABLES : PROPHETE
FICHIER UTILISE POUR LA REQUETE : &NOMFICHIER1
CONDITIONS D’EXTRACTION : TYPOLOGIE (CODANAPL2)=&CODEANA6CAR
LISTER LES DONNEES SUIVANTES : POLNO, CVGNO, DTREDUCTION
FICHIER UTILISE POUR LA FICHIER REQUETE : SDCONT
CONDITIONS D’EXTRACTION : CDPROD=\'OBS\'
AND CDETATCTR=20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 65, 66
AND VERIFONNUM=3
LISTER LES DONNEES"
```

The pattern I made use is : `/CONDITIONS D’EXTRACTION :(.*)(?=[AND\s]*)*/`
Replaced by : `(WHERE=( \1 ))`

The result matching the regexp wouldn't take the entire where condition :

```
- (WHERE=( FAMCNT=&TYCNT )) AND CGAR=&CODGAR CHARGER
- (WHERE=( TYPOLOGIE (CODANAPL2)=&CODEANA6CAR )) LISTER
- (WHERE=( CDPROD='OBS' )) AND CDETATCTR=20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 65, 66 AND VERIFONNUM=3 LISTER
```

I can't manage to create a regexp returning :

```
- (WHERE=( FAMCNT=&TYCNT  AND CGAR=&CODGAR ))  
-(WHERE=( TYPOLOGIE (CODANAPL2)=&CODEANA6CAR )) 
- (WHERE=( CDPROD='OBS'  AND CDETATCTR=20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 65, 66 AND VERIFONNUM=3  ))
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thx

Comment: @vks The last bloc of code should be the output. 
`(WHERE=(  \1 ))`.
I've tried the following regexp in notepad++:
`^CONDITIONS D[’|']EXTRACTION : (.*?)(LISTER|CHARGER)`
It seems to work, but used with php / preg-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONDITIONS D’EXTRACTION :([\s\S]*?)(?:CHARGER|LISTER)
```

Replace by `(WHERE=( $1 ))`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/6

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works just fine.
Thanks for the webtool too !